# Grouping columns and performing functions on subsets of columns

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
A1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
A2 <- c(2, 3, 4)
A3 <- c(3, 3, 2)
A4 <- c(2, 2, 3)
A5 <- c(4, 3, 5)
A6 <- c(6, 7, 2)
A7 <- c(1, 2, 5)
A8 <- c(2, 5, 5)
A9 <- c(2, 3, 5)
A10 <- c(7, 4, 2)
A11 <- c(7, 3, 2)
A12 <- c(9, 2, 1)
A13 <- c(1, 2, 5)
A14 <- c(2, 5, 5)
A15 <- c(2, 3, 5)
A16 <- c(7, 4, 2)
A17 <- c(7, 3, 2)
A18 <- c(9, 2, 1)
df <- cbind(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, A15, A16, A17, A18)
> df
     A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 A15 A16 A17 A18
[1,]  1  2  3  2  4  6  1  2  2   7   7   9   1   2   2   7   7   9
[2,]  2  3  3  2  3  7  2  5  3   4   3   2   2   5   3   4   3   2
[3,]  3  4  2  3  5  2  5  5  5   2   2   1   5   5   5   2   2   1
```

I would like to group the columns into groups of 6, and then within each of these groups, divide the first 3 columns by the second 3 (i.e., A1/A4, A2/A5, A3/A6, A7/A10, A8/A11, A9/A12, etc.) so that I end up with new columns that contain ratios (see below).

```
> df_new
      B1  B2        B3        B4        B5        B6        B7        B8        B9
[1,] 0.5 0.5 0.5000000 0.1428571 0.2857143 0.2222222 0.1428571 0.2857143 0.2222222
[2,] 1.0 1.0 0.4285714 0.5000000 1.6666667 1.5000000 0.5000000 1.6666667 1.5000000
[3,] 1.0 0.8 1.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 5.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 5.0000000
```

Is there a quick and efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `split` the dataset into `list` of data.frame by creating a grouping sequence with `gl`, then divide the first 3 columns, by the next 3 columns and `cbind` to create a single dataset

```
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(as.data.frame(df), 
    as.integer(gl(ncol(df), 6, ncol(df)))), function(x) x[1:3]/x[4:6]))
names(out) <- paste0("B", seq_along(out))
out
#   B1  B2        B3        B4        B5        B6        B7        B8        B9
#1 0.5 0.5 0.5000000 0.1428571 0.2857143 0.2222222 0.1428571 0.2857143 0.2222222
#2 1.0 1.0 0.4285714 0.5000000 1.6666667 1.5000000 0.5000000 1.6666667 1.5000000
#3 1.0 0.8 1.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 5.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 5.0000000
```

---

Another option is to subset the dataset by using logical vector (recycling) and then do the `/`

```
i1 <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 3)
out2 <- df[,i1]/df[,!i1]
colnames(out2) <- paste0("B", seq_len(ncol(out2)))

out2
#      B1  B2        B3        B4        B5        B6        B7        B8
#[1,] 0.5 0.5 0.5000000 0.1428571 0.2857143 0.2222222 0.1428571 0.2857143
#[2,] 1.0 1.0 0.4285714 0.5000000 1.6666667 1.5000000 0.5000000 1.6666667
#[3,] 1.0 0.8 1.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000 5.0000000 2.5000000 2.5000000
#            B9
#[1,] 0.2222222
#[2,] 1.5000000
#[3,] 5.0000000
```

NOTE: This should be more efficient compared to splitting